# How to nested multiple scrollview?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing an application in React native. I need to use more than one scrollview. But scrolling is only valid for the whole page. Others do not work while scrolling. My English is bad, please excuse me. Is there anyone who can help me with this? Thank you from now.

Sample line of code;

```
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <View style={styles.userRanking}>
                { 
                    (users.length > 0) ?
                    <ScrollView>
                        <FlatList
                            data={users}                                
                            renderItem={({item}) =>
                                <ListItem                                        
                                    title={item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name}
                                    subtitle={item.count + item.amount}
                                    bottomDivider={true}
                                />
                            }
                            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                        />
                    </ScrollView>
                }
            </View>

            <View style={styles.userRanking}>
                { 
                    (teams.length > 0) ?
                    <ScrollView>
                        <FlatList
                            data={teams}                                
                            renderItem={({item}) =>
                                <ListItem                                        
                                    title={item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name}
                                    subtitle={item.count + item.amount}
                                    bottomDivider={true}
                                />
                            }
                            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                        />
                    </ScrollView>
                }
            </View>

            <View style={styles.userRanking}>
                { 
                    (branchs.length > 0) ?
                    <ScrollView>
                        <FlatList
                            data={branchs}                                
                            renderItem={({item}) =>
                                <ListItem                                        
                                    title={item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name}
                                    subtitle={item.count + item.amount}
                                    bottomDivider={true}
                                />
                            }
                            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                        />
                    </ScrollView>
                }
            </View>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fixed. I use `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` and worked.